# SAML in Grails 3.3.x Certificate Issue in sp.xml

Tags: grails, groovy, saml-2.0

As per the documentation provided in https://jeffwils.github.io/grails-spring-security-saml/

1. Created SAML2.0 application in IDP(pingOne)
2. Created gralis application.
3. Added required( saml, spring-boot-starer-security, maven
   repositories) dependencies in build.gradle
4. Updated springsecurity, saml properties in application.yml file
5. Copied idp metadata xml into idp-local.xml
6. Created self signed certificate and used in sp.xml
7. Ran keystore command

While launching the application throwing this error **'Cannot sign outgoing message as no signing credential is set in the context'**. Can anyone provide steps to create sp.xml with certificate and ACS url.